# how to provide license key field for winforms setup and validate it befire installing setup?

Tags: winforms, c#-4.0, installation

I want to create a setup for my winforms application, my requirement is that i want to provide a field for the user to enter license key and that key will be validated with the help of webservice with my database..

If the user enters the correct key then after submitting the setup should be installed otherwise, the setup should not be installed..

My problem here , all the coding i do in my application will work only after i install and run the installed setup, but while installing itself how can i provide the license key field and textbox and calling webservice on button click...the user should not be able to install the setup if he is not providing the valid license key...

Im creating the setup with visual studio setup project...I want to give the same functionality thet we notice generally in softwares in the market..

Comment: there are infinite solutions to this problem, can you provide more detail please.

Comment: im creating the setup of my project with visual studio setup project template, after creating the setup .exe and i give it to the enduser, buti want to provide a textfield for the user to enter license key and validate it, but i can do it in my application but that works only after the exe gets installed and the user runs it but want to do it before installing?